# Must embedding of $X$ in $Y$ be open ($X$, $Y$ $n$-manifolds)?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Is it true, that having an open ball $B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (say $n=2$, but the more general answer the better) and a set $C$ such that $0 \in \overline{C}$, there is *no* open neighbourhood of $0$ in $B(0,1)\setminus C$ homeomorphic with $B(0,1)$.

This comes from something with less technical wording: is it true, that image of every embedding of an $n$-manifold into another $n$-manifold is open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question (in the title) is the content of the [invariance of domain theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) of Brouwer. For a proof (using the Brouwer fixed point theorem) you can see [Terry Tao's blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/).

Comment: Yes! That is what I needed.